# Criar animação "FadeOut"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A tabela é criada pelo código javascript, quando clicada em um item de outra tabela, mas ela não possui animação. A animação que quero colocar é de "FadeOut". Quando for clicado o item da tabela, ela deve aparecer com o efeito "FadeOut". Tentei usar o FadeToggle, mas não consegui.

**Ajax:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* Função Ajax, consulta no banco de dados */
        function mostra_ocorrencias(nome_aluno){
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200){
                    document.getElementById('relatorio').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","pesquisa_individual.php?nome_aluno="+nome_aluno,true);
            document.querySelector('relatorio').innerHTML = xmlhttp.send(); 
            // $("#relatorio").fadeToggle();
        }
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<tr onclick="mostra_ocorrencias(id)">
```

**Código PHP (pesquisa_individual.php):**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","eeep");
mysql_select_db("alunos",$con);
$sql = "select tipo from ocorrencias where nome_aluno = '".$_GET['nome_aluno']."'";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql,$con) or mysql_error();
$falta=0;
$Falta_Justificada=0;
$Fardamento_Incompleto=0;
$ES_Autorizada=0;
$Indisciplina=0;
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    if($linha['tipo']=="Falta"){
        $falta++;
    }
    if($linha['tipo']=="Falta Justificada"){
        $Falta_Justificada++;
    }
    if($linha['tipo']=="Fardamento Incompleto"){
        $Fardamento_Incompleto++;
    }
    if($linha['tipo']=="Entrada/Saída Autorizada"){
        $ES_Autorizada++;
    }
    if($linha['tipo']=="Indisciplína"){
        $Indisciplina++;
    }
}


**// A Tabela é criada aqui!** 


echo "<table id='relatorio_v'>
    <tr>
        <td class='vermelho'>Falta</td>
        <td class='laranja'>Falta Justificada</td>
        <td class='azul'>Fardamento Incompleto</td>
        <td class='verde'>Entrada/Saída Autorizada</td>
        <td class='marron'>Indisciplína</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='vermelho'>".$falta."</td>
        <td class='laranja'>".$Falta_Justificada."</td>
        <td class='azul'>".$Fardamento_Incompleto."</td>
        <td class='verde'>".$ES_Autorizada."</td>
        <td class='marron'>".$Indisciplina."</td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
```

?>

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](https://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html).

Comment: Esse trecho necessita do JQuery `$("#relatorio").fadeToggle();` e aparentemente não está usando JQuery. Adicione a library do JQuery e então terá o efeito desejado. Removi o PHP das tags e tudo mais porque PHP não tem relação alguma com o assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso apenas com CSS você precisa de duas classes. Uma que ira esconder e outra que ira exibir o elemento.

Inicialmente sua tabela terá a class `.hide`, após realizar o carregamento das informações você ira montar a tabela da forma que precisa e remover a class `.hide` adicionando a `.show`
`css
.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s .5s, opacity .5s linear;
}`

Você disse que tentou usar o fadeToggle. Você precisa verificar o seguinte.

1. ID da tabela no código que enviou é #relatorio_v e no javascript voce usou #relatorio.
2. Você tem o jquery no seu html ?
3. Como você monta a tabela por um ajax talvez o jquery não esteja encontrando o ID no DOM do html no momento do click.
4. Como são varias linhas e varias tabelas talvez ID não funcione.

Obs: o efeito que você procura é FadeIn e não o FadeOut como disse :)

Comment: Na verdade o #relatorio é o id da primeira tabela que ao ser clicada irá criar a tabela que está com o id #relatorio_v. Posso inserir o jquery no html. Como poderia mudar a classe ?